# How to delete checked words from a list in Flutter

Tags: flutter

In Flutter, I have a List of words(ListView), I have a trailing check box, how to delete the checked items from the list keeping the others intact.
Apologies in advance if am wrong in asking the question, because i am new to flutter framework.

Comment: Add your code to better explain what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your onPressed function for the checkbox where words would be the list of the words:

```
setState(() {
  words.removeAt(index);
});
```

Snippet from [Implement swipe to dismiss](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/gestures/dismissible) guide by Flutter's cookbook which also explains how to [work with lists and listViews](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook#lists).